# Is it possible in javascript to do "number plus negative number"?

Tags: javascript, sum, negative-number

I'm trying to make function, which changes the height of DOM element.

```
    function _changeLiHeight( elem, height ) {
        var area = elem.parent( '.area' ),
            li = area.parents( 'li' ),
            outerh = li.outerHeight( true );

        li.css( 'height', outerh + height );
    }
```

I expected to have a result like 100 + -30 = 70, but when I send a negative number as second argument, the result is 100 + -30 = -30. Is this behavior okay and how to solve my problem?

Mistake was that I send deleted element as first argument, so true, outerh was 0.

Comment: Are you sure the `outerh` is `100`? it's more like `0`

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of this? Something someone can run in their console, or (even better), a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function sum(x,y){
      console.log(x+y);
}

sum(100,-30);
```

Output : 70 .

It works fine . Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/KW3kb/ .

Comment: Mistake was that I send deleted element as first argument, so true, outerh was 0.